# How do I find what performs port forwarding?

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding

I configured port forwarding 6 months ago somehow on one of my AWS EC2 servers but I can't remember how.

It's Amazon Linux instance. I thought I used iptables but rules table reveals anything.

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:6379
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:11181
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:6380
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:15672
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:amqp

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Something forwards requests from 80 to 9000 (of app running in docker container).

How do I find it ?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that I had to use `iptables -t nat -S` to see NAT rules.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your case but if you could remind with this answer. For port forward I use this kind of command as nat type :

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp  -d INPUT_IP_ADRESS --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination OUTPUT_IP_ADRESSS:9000
```

I put output address because I accustomed to use 2 network interfaces. Don't forget to use `iptables-save` if it's working (joking)